# How to return arbitrary type in C++11 using auto keyword?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Container {
    public:
        Container(){
            Doubles["pi"] = 3.1415;
            Doubles["e"] = 2.7182;

            Integers["one"] = 1;
            Integers["two"] = 2;
        }

        // Bracket.cpp:23:9: error: 'auto' return without trailing return type
        // auto& operator[](const std::string&);
        auto& operator[](const std::string& key);

    private:
        std::map<std::string, double> Doubles;
        std::map<std::string, int> Integers;
};
```

I'd like to overload the `operator[]` function to return something from either `Doubles` or `Integers` depending on a key that is passed. However, I don't know *a prioi* if what will be returned is a `double` or a `int`. I'd like to implement the `operator[]` function in this way:

```
// Compiler error
// Bracket.cpp:30:1: error: 'auto' return without trailing return type
// auto& Container::operator[](const std::string& key){
auto& Container::operator[](const std::string& key){
    std::cout << "I'm returning the value associated with key: " 
              << key << std::endl;

    auto D_search = Doubles.find(key);
    if (D_search != Doubles.end()){
        std::cout << "I found my key in Doubles with value: " << 
            D_search->second << std::endl;

        return D_search->second;
    }
    else{
        auto I_search = Integers.find(key);
        if (I_search != Integers.end()){
            std::cout << "I found my key in Integers with value: " << 
                I_search->second << std::endl;

            return I_search->second;
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "I didn't find a value for the key." << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

**Is there a way to create a single `operator[]` function to return multiple types?**

This was driven with this simple code:

```
int main(){

    Container Bucket;

    double pi(Bucket["pi"]);

    std::cout << "The value of pi is: " << pi << std::endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You can't overload based on return type alone.

Comment: `auto` is not some sort of black magic that suddenly allows a function to have multiple return types. In this case, since `int` is convertible to `double`, you can just return the latter, but, in general, what you're asking for is not possible. Create separate functions, or return a Boost.Variant or some such thing if you must have a single function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C++11 version of `auto` as return type only allows you to postpone the return type declaration until after the function parameters have been declared:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto add(T1 x, T2 y) -> decltype(x + y) { return x + y; }
```

Here you can't write `decltype(x + y) add(...)` because the compiler doesn't know what `x` and `y` are.

The C++14 version of `auto` permits return type deduction by the compiler. It tells the compiler to deduce the return type of the function based on the body, but it's still a single return type, so it still does not do what you want.

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't do that.  A function must have a single return type that's known at compile time; `auto` just saves you from having to *type* it when the compiler can figure out from context what it must be.

You can use a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), or a class that wraps one such as [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html), to hold different types of values depending on runtime decisions.  This can give you the effect of having a changeable return type.

Comment: Note that Boost.Variant is (currently) of limited usefulness in C++11, since it does not properly handle move constructors and so on. A tagged union is definitely the way to go (and the Boost.Variant interface is a good one), but you may need to use a different implementation (or write your own!),

Answer (score 3):

C++ lacks functions that return multiple disjoint types.

You can emulate that language feature by using `boost::variant` or similar tagged unions, but that places it as a job on the caller to get the type right.  You can also use apply functors (which `boost::variant` does with the visitor syntax) that you require to handle both overloads (far easier to write in C++1y thanks to `[](auto){}` lambdas).

If you assume the caller knows the type, you can just expose two different functions depending on the type.  If you want a relatively uniform interface, you can have a `template` function with specializations based on type, but I would only sometimes advise that.  Exceptions or errors can detail "you got the type wrong" if needed (ie, if you have a rule that each name only maps to one type).

If you do not assume the caller knows the type, then you must return an object that allows some kind of query asto the type of the object (at run time).  The `visitor` of `boost::variant` is one way to do this so they gain a type-safe view after the fact.  `IUnknown`/`dynamic_cast` style queries are also popular, but pretty meh honestly.

There are as well a number of hacks you can do.

You can assume the caller knows the type of the tagged data, and return a pseudo-reference that has `operator int` and `operator double` overloads, and does something (throws?  casts?  asserts?  returns `0`?) if the caller gets the type wrong.

You can use exceptions to emulate multiple return types:

```
int get_foo( std::string bob ) {
  if (bob == "alice")
    throw 3.14;
  else
    return 7;
}
int main() {
  try {
    int x = get_foo("alice");
    std::cout << x << "\n";
  } except( double d ) {
    std::cout << d << "\n";
  }
}
```

but that is horrid.

One could imagine a language that supported this:

```
int|double get_foo( std::string bob ) {
  if (bob=="alice")
    return double{3.14};
  else
    return int(7);
}
int main() {
   int|double x = bob("alice");
   std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

which, as the assembly level, would push 2 return locations into `bob` (depending on which of the return types it returns) and 2 (possibly overlapping) spots to write said return value, and then `bob` would write to one of them and return to the appropriate spot in the calling code.  All code after that in the caller would have to be 'forked' to deal with the two possible types of the return value.

But that language is not C++.  All expressions in C++ must be of a single known type which is not dependent on run-time parameters or even `constexpr` parameters passed as arguments.

`boost::variant` emulates a value that is more than one type, but it really is one type (`boost::variant<double, int>`) that lets you access the contained types.

Comment: yes if you try your little example with auto then you get inconsistent deduction for 'auto': 'double' and then 'int'
It would be an improvement if auto could handle this - maybe in the future

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `Doubles` has a key `key` and if not, check for `Integers` and throw an exception if neither contain that key:

```c++
auto Container::operator[](const std::string& key)
    -> decltype(find_double(key) ? Doubles->second : Integers->second);

bool find_double(const std::string& key) const
{
    return Doubles.find(key) != Doubles.end();
}

bool find_integer(const std::string& key) const
{
    return Integers.find(key) != Integers.end();
}
```

Then inside `operator[]` you do:

```c++
return find_double(key)  ? Doubles->second
     : find_integer(key) ? Integers->second
     : throw std::invalid_argument("Could not find key: " + key);
```

Comment: That is a lot of typing to say "`->double`".

Answer (score 0):

### A Hack

You can only create a class that overloads several conversion operators:

```
struct FooReturnProxy {
    FooReturnProxy (int val) : val(val) {}

    operator int() const {
        return val*2;
    }

    operator std::string() const {
        return "Dizzle izzle dolizzle black boom shackalack tempizzle";
    }

    // and so on

private:
    int val;
};


FooReturnProxy foo() {
    return FooReturnProxy(42);
}

int main () {
    int x = foo():
    std::string y = foo();
}
```

You could also make those conversion operators templates.

Alternatively, you could use `boost::any` to allow for any type.

### However ...

However, given that no one really uses such method in the C++ community, this can at best be considered a hack. The real solution probably requires you to review your design at a higher level. Do you really *need* it? Or do you just *want* it? If only the latter, better refrain from the solution presented here (except for exploring C++, of course).

Answer (score 0):

C++ is designed to be statically typed for safety.  However you could re-design turning things inside out to use polymorphism to get the effect you want.

The idea would be to define a general number type, storing in the lookup map key/object references.  Sub-classes of number for double & int implement the operations required like stringify, and mathematical operations and conversions, to permit exact integer addition/subtraction or convenient floating point multiplication & division.

The advantage of an object oriented design, would be if later you needed to add yet more implementation types of class number, perhaps for infinite precision, without affecting alogorithmns developed using object methods.  For desk calculator type problems, that is most likely over elaborate.