# Class to represent reciprocals

Tags: c++, types, operators

I have code where I do a lot things like

```
a = 1/((1/b)+(1/c))
```

I can't help it, I cringe at the use of so many divisions, when I could do it like this

```
oneOverA = oneOverB + oneOverC
```

In fact i can do pretty much everything with reciprocals. For instance with comparisons

```
A < B iff oneOverB < oneOverA
```

again without need to divide. And so on.

However, this would be extremely error-prone. Imagine if I pass the reversed version to a function which expects the "straight" one, or forget to reverse the order while comparing, etc.

But, C++ exists to make magic happen, right?

And if I implenent a very simple class header-only, pretty much everything should be optimized away; leaving it just as I would write it if I was as infallible as the compiler.

So I tried a class like

```
template<typename T = float>  //T must be a type for which 1/T is representable as another T such that 1(1/T)) = T. es. float
class ReversibleNum{
private:
    const T reverse; 
public: 
    ReversibleNum(T orig): reverse(1/orig) {} 
    operator T () { return 1/reverse; }                    
    bool operator < (const ReversibleNum<T>& oth) { return oth.reverse < reverse; } 
    friend T operator / (const T one, const ReversibleNum<T>& two);
}

inline T operator / (const T one, const ReversibleNum<T>& two)  { return one * two.reverse; }
```

However, when I try

```
 ReversibleNum<float> a(5);
 1.0/a
```

it uses "operator float" to convert and then divide, rather than "operator /" which is what I want.

I could probably make "operator T" explicit. However I like the idea of being able to use it seamlessy and have the conversion just happen; but only when there really is no alternative.

Is there something I can do to make my code work?

Or maybe some different, more advanced magic I coud use to achieve my aim?

Comment: Your problem is that `1.0` is a `double` not a `float`.  Depending on the generality you want, you could define some template on two types: `auto operator/( T1 const& one, ReversibleNum<T2>const& two)  { return one * two.reverse; }`  But that may need to be SFINAE narrowed to disable some `T1` cases you don't want.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works. However, I have to write 1.0f/, which is ugly. Ideally, it should work even whith 1/. Or, I can declare operator / as using two independent template types. It's not obvious what the return type should be then, however.

Comment: I haven't used `auto` much yet.  So I think (but I'm not sure) that the return type is as easy as I showed above, IF you don't need to use SFINAE to narrow the choices of T1.  If you do need SFINAE there, the return type deduction is mixed into the SFINAE

Comment: I'm note sure I will need SFINAE, but 'auto' as a return type seems to be a C++14 trick, and my 4.4.7 gcc (I am working on CentOS) does not support it yet.

Comment: I think in C++11 you just need the redundant `-> decltype` to use `auto`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831743/how-to-return-arbitrary-type-in-c11-using-auto-keyword

Comment: That is correct I believe, but I can't do it in GCC 4.4.7 because of a bug that no one fixed until 4.8.0. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52816 Just... why (as far as I understand decltype) I can't say "the type of the result of the multiplication of this type and this type", and instead I need to actually use a variable of that type?

Comment: That sounds like just an access control issue.  If so, it should be easy to work around without needing a compiler version in which it is fixed.  Try `auto operator/( T1 const& one, ReversibleNum<T2>const& two) ->decltype(one*(T2)(two)) { return one * two.reverse; }`

Comment: Right! It didn't even occur to me I could use a different, public expression with the same type... however, now the division operator is back to being ignored in favor of conversion one. Maybe auto has a low priority?

Comment: That doesn't seem right.  Can you edit the original code to show current code including exact template specification of the function that isn't found.

Comment: Not actually contributing to the core problem: why would you execute `reverse *= oth` in the implementation of `operator /=`? You mean `reverse /= oth`, right?

Comment: @JSF I ended up using an implemetation which assumes the return type is the same as the template parameter of my class, as I can't see a situation where this wouldn't make sense enough. It would be interesting to know what happened... maybe if I still can't understand when I try again I can post a new question about it, and link it here if you're interested.

Comment: @ChristophFreundl but reverse is a denominator. dividing by a number is multiplying the denominator by that number.

Comment: The return type would not change the overload selection **unless** your coding error and/or a compiler bug eliminated the function by SFINAE (so that seems to be the reason overload resolution went wrong).  In the original case of `double/ReversibleNum<float>` I think returning `float` instead of `double` is a serious flaw.  So I think you should find a correction to that SFINAE glitch.

Comment: @Francesco Probably I got the semantics wrong, I understood that e.g. `ReversibleNum<>(5.0)` represents the number `1/5.0` whose value is stored in `reverse`. So, if you divide that number by let's say `2` the result would be `1/10.0` which means that in the internal representation `reverse` would also have to be divided (not multplied) by 2 to get the same result. However, if you internally store the `5.0` instead of `1/5.0`, then the division would be realized by multiplication, of course.

Comment: By the way, I just realized that the initialization `reverse(1/T)` is invalid (`T` is a type). Maybe you can correct the code, probably you meant either `reverse(1/orig)` or rather `reverse(orig)` because in the latter case the multiplication in the `operator /=` would be correct. Also the `operator T()` should rather return `1/reverse` then (`1/T` should not even compile, I would guess).

Comment: @ChristophFreundl in my mind, ReversibleNum(5.0) represents 5.0, as to make the conversion seamless -if I pass a float to a function expecting ReversibleNum<float>, it construct the right object. But internally the 5.0 is stored as 1/5.0.

Comment: @ChristophFreundl you are right about the T, I must have copied an old backup version of a not yet working prototype. I fixed it.

Comment: @Francesco Ok, then I got it wrong in fact ;-) After the last edit of the question there is still an issue in the `operator T()`: `return 1/orig;` is not possible (`orig` is not a member variable), did you mean `return 1/reverse`?

Comment: @ChristophFreundl you're right again. I might be overreliant on compiler errors to get my code right after all... or maybe StackOverflow should add an online comiler -then it would enforce minimal working code which actually works!