# std::function - function uses ‘auto’ type specifier without trailing return type in C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm trying to get a C++14 library working with our C++ 11 code base and having trouble with using `std::function` (of which I know very little).

Minimal code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
    
    using CallbackFn = std::function<int(int, double)>;
    auto GetCallbackFn() const { return mCallbackFcn.target<int (*)(int, double)>(); }

private:
   CallbackFn mCallbackFcn;

};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hi there\n";
}
```

The code compiles without error with C++14 but with C++11 produces an error:

```
main.cpp:20:5: error: ‘GetCallbackFn’ function uses ‘auto’ type specifier without trailing return type
```

I've tried replacing `auto` with `CallbackFn` and other permutations but all end up with one error or another.

How do I modify the code to compile under C++11?

Thanks

Comment: `auto GetCallbackFn() const -> decltype(mCallbackFcn.target<int (*)(int, double)>()) {/*..*/}`. (or `-> int (*)(int, double)`)

Comment: The returned type is `int (*)(int, double)` (preferably as an alias).

Comment: Sometimes (when you have enough unit tests) it is more easy to upgrade a compiler then to backport libraries. At least make sure you unit test the backport too

Comment: @Yksisarvinen The returned type is `int (* const*)(int, double)`, there's another pointer level added.

Comment: @interjay Oops, you're right!

Comment: See [How to return arbitrary type in C++11 using auto keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831743/how-to-return-arbitrary-type-in-c11-using-auto-keyword)

Comment: That is because return type deduction is allowed since C++14. In C++11 you have to explicitly write the trailing return type.

Comment: I recommend uplifting the C++11 codebase to C++14, rather than backporting the C++14 library to C++11.  Time better spent.  (My project is over 50 million lines of code. We uplifted it from pre-C++ standard to C++98, then to C++14, then to C++17.  I'm aware of the effort involved.)

Comment: @Eljay that is the preference, but sometimes you can be stuck on a legacy toolchain because of hardware